# hive can't create table by hiveserver2

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm build a simplest hive server(v2.1.1) and want create a simple table on it. but a error encounter:

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from 
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.
 MetaException(message:file:/user/hive/warehouse/test2 is not a directory
 or unable to create one)
```

my sql on CLI is `create table test2(id int)` which is very simple.
I have test the sql on CLI both of `hive` and `beeline`, besides, JDBC also has the same error output.

Other things:
1. `show tables` works fine.
2. configs under < project-dir > /config/:
    1) hive-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
        <value>jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.230:3306/hive?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
        <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>    
    </property>   
    <property> 
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name> 
        <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value> 
        <description>Driver class name for a JDBC metastore</description>     
    </property>               

    <property> 
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
        <value>hive</value>
        <description>username to use against metastore database</description>
    </property>
    <property>  
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
        <value>hive</value>
        <description>password to use against metastore database</description>  
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hive.server2.enable.impersonation</name>
        <description>Enable user impersonation for HiveServer2</description>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

2) hive-default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
        <value>jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.230:3306/hive?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
        <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>    
    </property>   
    <property> 
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name> 
        <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value> 
        <description>Driver class name for a JDBC metastore</description>     
    </property>               

    <property> 
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
        <value>hive<value>
        <description>username to use against metastore database</description>
    </property>
    <property>  
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
        <value>hive</value>
        <description>password to use against metastore database</description>  
    </property>
</configuration>
```

3) core-site.xml for hadoop user config

```
<configuration>
 <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hadoop.groups</name>
      <value>*</value>
      <description>Allow the superuser oozie to impersonate any members of the group group1 and group2</description>
 </property>

 <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hadoop.hosts</name>
      <value>*</value>
      <description>The superuser can connect only from host1 and host2 to impersonate a user</description>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

3. presto can create table in the hive by presto-cli which connect by hive.metastore.uri.
4. I have ensure hdfs `/user/hive/warehouse` directory is chmod 755 by other SO topic advice.

I have struggle a whole day. Hope any advice. Thanks

**UPDATE**
also fail with create databse:

```
hive> create database testdb;
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:Unable to create database path file:/user/hive/warehouse/testdb.db, failed to create database testdb)
```

**UPDATE**
I think it maybe a setting problem with hdfs's user but I'm not sure where I can find all relative settings.

Comment: My first guess is a rights/user issue. Does it help if you chmod 777 temporarily? (Or even create the required directory and chmod 777 that).

Comment: Not works with `hadoop fs -chmod 777 /user/hive/warehouse`. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Are you able to create a database (and a table in that?) I am not sure whether tables can be created directly in the warehouse (normally you would at least have a default database or so)

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin, fail to create database.....and I'm remember default database's table saved at warehouse dir.

Comment: Try creating an external table with file location to a space where you have access. It seems the Hive userID is not able to write data to the metastore.

Comment: what is the property **hive.metastore.warehouse.dir**  value present in your hive-site.xml?

Comment: @vasanth, I'm not setting. It should be use default value with /user/hive/warehouse.

Comment: It is trying to get the location from local. Ensure hive-site.xml has the configuration like this `<property>
<name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
<value>hdfs://CP000187:9000/user/hive/warehouse</value>
<description>location of default database for the warehouse</description> 
</property>`

Comment: @vasanth, Same error occurred. I add `/user/hive/warehouse` as the property's value. Because I don't know `hdfs fs` shell cmd default addr and port. I can use `hdfs fs -ls /user/hive/warehouse` access `/user/hive/warehouse` on the hive server machine.

Comment: You would have given the address and port in hadoop core-site.xml as the following property's value `<name>fs.default.name</name>`.check that and replace appropirately.

Comment: @vasanth, thanks a lot.I finally find it's matter of `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir`, I must setting full path to hdfs: `hdfs://127.0.0.0.1:9000/user/hive/warehouse`, otherwise, `/user/hive/warehouse` means local path (not hdfs).

Comment: @LoranceChen Glad it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is trying to get the location from local. Ensure hive-site.xml has the configuration like this

```
<property>
<name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
<value>hdfs://CP000187:9000/user/hive/warehouse</value>
<description>location of default database for the
warehouse</description> 
</property>
```